# ParameterSetName and Positions. Wrong set being picked up

Tags: powershell, overloading

I'm trying to do an overload style method similar to

```csharp
// C#
public void Foo (string xmlFilePathAndName, 
                 string environment, 
                 bool preventWrite) {}

public void Foo (string xmlFilePathAndName, 
                 string xmlTransformFilePathAndName, 
                 string environment, 
                 bool preventWrite) {}
```

and so essentially I've written this.

```posh
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="default")]
param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='default', Position=0)] 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Overload1', Position=0)] 
    [string] $xmlFilePathAndName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='default', Position=1)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Overload1', Position=2)] 
    [string] $environment,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='default', Position=2)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='Overload1', Position=3)] 
    [switch] $preventWrite,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Overload1', Position=1)]
    [string] [alias('xdt')] $xmlTransformFilePathAndName

)


switch($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName){
    "default" {  
        "default"
        break
    }
    "Overload1" {  
        "Overload1"
        break
    }
}
```

And here are my test calls
*note: the important thing here is that `$environment` needs to be second for default and third when `$xmlTransformFilePathAndName` exists.*

```posh
Invoke-XmlDocTransform "c:\somepath\web.config" 'local'  #expect Default
# result: Default     [PASSED]

Invoke-XmlDocTransform "c:\somepath\local.xml""c:\somepath\global.xml" 'local' -preventWrite # expect Overload1
# result: Default     [FAILED]

# I never want to use the below approach.
Invoke-XmlDocTransform "c:\somepath\local.xml" -xdt "c:\somepath\global.xml" 'local' -preventWrite # expect Overload1
# result: Overload1   [PASSED]
```

Notice in the second call, I'm not getting the expected result, but in the third, I am.

I really don't want to have to add the `-xdt` parameter declaration in order to get this working, I'd rather have it just obey the positional parameters... IE: If there's a string in the third position, use the overload, otherwise, don't.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the behavior, but AFAICS the parameter sets are handled the way you want if you change the parameter order to this:

1. parameters that are mandatory in both sets
2. other mandatory parameters
3. optional parameters

Code:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="default")]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='default', Position=0)] 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Overload1', Position=0)] 
    [string] $xmlFilePathAndName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='default', Position=1)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Overload1', Position=1)] 
    [string] $environment,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Overload1', Position=2)]
    [string] [alias('xdt')] $xmlTransformFilePathAndName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='default', Position=2)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='Overload1', Position=3)]
    [switch] $preventWrite
)
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 "c:\somepath\local.xml" 'local' "c:\somepath\global.xml"
Overload1
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 "c:\somepath\local.xml" 'local' "c:\somepath\global.xml" -preventWrite
Overload1
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 "c:\somepath\local.xml" 'local' -preventWrite
default
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 "c:\somepath\local.xml" 'local'
default
```

Comment: yes, this is true, and I was able to do the same thing, however I want `local` in the third position, not the second.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say i know exactly how positional parameter sets work but i got your code to work by removing the second position and giving each parameter a unique position number.

```
function Invoke-XmlDocTransform
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="default",
                   PositionalBinding=$true)]
    param(

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='default', Position=0)] 
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Overload1')] 
        [string] $xmlFilePathAndName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='default', Position=1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Overload1')] 
        [string] $environment,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='default', Position=3)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Overload1')] 
        [switch] $preventWrite,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Overload1', Position=2)]
        [string] [alias('xdt')] $xmlTransformFilePathAndName

    )


    switch($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
    {
        "default"
        {  
            "default"
            break
        }
        "Overload1"
        {  
            "Overload1"
            break
        }
    }

    $PSBoundParameters
}
```

Which gives me the result

```
Invoke-XmlDoctransform 'this' 'that'
Default

Invoke-XmlDocTransform 'this' 'that' -PreventWrite
Default

Invoke-XmlDocTransform 'this' 'that' 'them'
Overload1

Invoke-XmlDocTransform 'this' 'that' 'them -PreventWrite
Overload1
```